# C# Whats better to program a RPG, xna or monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I want to make an RPG and want to know if i should use Xna or Monogame to code it. What would have a better result or easier code. I've researched a bit but still cant decide.

Comment: XNA is not supported any more while MonoGame is. Choice is up to you, nobody can tell you what to choose.

Comment: That depends. Please read the tipps on what questions should be asked here and which ones not. This belongs to the later group, as it is oppinion-based.

Comment: The primary difference between MonoGame and XNA is the supported platforms (operating systems). So the fact that you are making an RPG makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Monogame is the open source version of XNA ...

In terms of API calls / code you would have to write to do something they are basically the same and were designed to be.

That's like asking ... "should I drive a blue car or a red car?" it makes no difference since both will get you from A to B.